# Sharing Yu-Gi-Oh! card ideas

Tags: yu-gi-oh, game-development

I have designed a few Yu-Gi-Oh! cards, and I want Konami to review them.

Is there a way to submit my designs so that Konami will see and consider them?

Comment: I would assume you mean an official submission process? Otherwise, you can easily publish it anywhere on the web.

Comment: Even if you could find a way to submit cards to Konami, I think that they would dismiss them out of hand if you refer to them as "yugioh" cards instead of "Yu-Gi-Oh!" cards. Not taking the time to properly spell or capitalize the name of the game you are submitting to does not show a lot of professionalism.

Comment: @Thunderforge , I wrote this very quickly because of lack of time. I will change it asap

Comment: @VortexYT What about the title?

Answer (score 12):

Konami has [general contact information](https://www.konami.com/games/us/en/pages/contact_us/) for their offices. However, I highly doubt that they will accept unsolicited card suggestions. There are a couple of reasons for that:

- They are already paying people to design cards, and they have a lot more experience.
- If they were to accept fan-submitted cards, you would not be the only person submitting them. Konami would have to pay people to sift through all of the thousands of submissions.
- Fan-submitted cards might have rights or legal issues. Do you own the card? Does Konami own the card? What happens if you submit a card and they radically change it? Do you have any say over the final outcome?
- If Konami is like most TCG companies, they already have hundreds if not thousands of cards that they would love to publish someday (they plan out new sets well over a year in advance too). They have no need for half a dozen cards from a fan.

Konami has to date released [16 fan-made cards](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Fan-Made_Cards). Out of those, 15 of them were winners of contests that Konami specifically held, usually "draw a monster" contests open only to children. The last one, [Tyler the Great Warrior](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Tyler_the_Great_Warrior), was a Make a Wish Foundation wish for a 14-year-old cancer patient (who ultimately survived). As best I can tell, all of these fan-submissions were only for monster designs and not for card stats.

Given this, I think your chances are practically zero for being able to show a card to Konami. Your best bet is to participate in one of these fan contests they have, or if you are an adult, convince a child to draw a monster that matches your design.

Comment: You suggest to have a child submit your idea, which seems like something that wouldn't necessarily be allowed (otherwise, why have the age cap at all?) I'm not familiar with those contests at all, but it seems like information worth adding to this answer, at least as a comment.

Comment: @TheThirdMan It was meant to be a tongue-in-cheek way of saying you should convince a child to draw your design. You're right, you can't just hand a child a drawing and have them submit it. I've changed the wording to make it clearer.

Comment: WotC claims a major issue with fan submissions is "What if *we* design a card, and then you claim it's derived from one you submitted?" Which is why there's a posted blanket policy of "if you send us something unsolicited, we won't look at it at all." Wouldn't surprise me if other TCG/gaming companies had similar standing rules.